# Call the first string from json

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, jsonp

This is the wikipedia link for the "wiki search" and callback "wikipedia".

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=wiki&callback=wikipedia

I use something like the following

```
function wikipedia(w){
   alert(w)
}
```

This gives me the autosuggestions, but it gives me whole code. Is there any javascript code that can call, for example the first result of this json.

I have tried many like the following

```
w[1]
w.wiki[0]
```

but no success.

Comment: The link shows a function wikipedia(the data); does 'w' in your code means the same data with the function and all?

Comment: Also found why I got the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined ", that was because the code was written badly and the function was called (two times) one was before the data were received from wikipedia

Answer (score 3):

The list of suggestions is available in `w[1]`, and you need to iterate through that list to do something with it.

Comment: @Amden So the real problem is that `w` is undefined then?

Answer (score 2):

you have to parse this JSON string into an object, if you know jQuery you can try [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Comment: What's wrong with the native `JSON.parse`?

Comment: just as @Kolink mentioned, you can use JSON.parse, I just didn't realize that it is already implemented

Comment: Since it's JSON-P, `w` is actually not a string containing JSON but already an object. Just have a look at the link.

Comment: true, here is the working example: [http://jsfiddle.net/5qUFF/](http://jsfiddle.net/5qUFF/)

Comment: exactly what I wanted, thanks to all of you.

Comment: @Amden: Do you really need to use `JSON.parse` (or equivalent)? Because the way the function is called, `w` will already be an object. If you are not actually parsing any JSON, you should not accept this answer (no offense Pawel).

Comment: You are right Felix, It's an object.

Answer (score 2):

If w[1] is throwing that error like you say, there is probably something else wrong with your code.  If you can use jQuery I'd strongly recommend it for jsonp.  This code does what you ask:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hg4KJ/

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=wiki&callback=wikipedia',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    callback: 'wikipedia'
}).done(function(w){
    var items = w[1];

    for(var i = 0, il = items.length; i < il; i++){
        console.log(items[i]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function wikipedia(w) {
    "use strict";
    var j = w;//JSON.parse(w); as commented, no need to parse.
    alert(j[1]);
}
```

If you're not using jQuery anyway.

Comment: Since it's JSON-P, `w` is actually not a string containing JSON but already an object. Just have a look at the link.